# adding an action for click event on picturebox in c#

Tags: c#, events, click, picturebox

**I get a pictureboxe and try to add it an action to change background Image upon click event happen, but there is no action. So, this is the code:**

```
pieces bishopBB = new pieces();        
public Form1()
        {              
         // object of picturebox
            bishopBB.Location = new Point(300, 455);
            bishopBB.Parent = this;
            bishopBB.Click += new System.EventHandler(pictureboxes_Click)
            InitializeComponent();
        }
private void pictureboxes_Click(object sender, EventArges e)
       {
            backgroundImage = Properties.Resources.black;
       }
```

Comment: Do you want to change the Background image of the form, or change the current image in the PictureBox control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the name and other indicators I would assume (and hope) that `pictureboxes_Click` is a **common** click handler for **many** `PictureBoxes`.

So to access the one that has been clicked you need to **cast** `sender` to `PictureBox` and then set the `BackgroundImage`:

```
private void pictureboxes_Click(object sender, EventArges e)
{
   ((PictureBox)sender).BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.black;
}
```

I'm a little amazed though that your spelling of `backgroundImage` compiles. The correct spelling `BackgroundImage` refers to the current class, usually the `Form` and it should also show, unless your `Form` has a black background already..

Answer (score 0):

To change the current image of the PictureBox control, you need to refer to the control and reference the BackgroundImage property (not 'backgroundImage'):

```
   private void pictureboxes_Click(object sender, EventArges e)
   {
        this.pictureboxes.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.black;
   }
```

To change the background image of the form:

```
    private void pictureboxes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.black;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can use the on_click property of the picturebox. You can then use the like picbox.image = whatever the image location is